What happens to a trial if the presiding judge is unable to finish the trial?
What happens if, during an ongoing trial, the presiding judge dies, is injured, or otherwise is unable to finish the trial?

Google found this: https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_63

@Barmar It's more complex than that. It's a potential mistrial. As your link says, a judge takes over only when he "determine[s] that the case may be completed without prejudice to the parties." What are the issues? It's very difficult for a judge to step in the middle of a bench trial.

canada
Criminal trials
Under s. 669.2 of the Criminal Code, where a judge dies or is for any reason unable to continue, the proceedings may be continued before another judge.
If it was a judge-alone trial, the judge shall "commence the trial again as if no evidence on the merits had been taken."
If there was a jury, the judge may

continue the trial, or
commence the trial again as if no evidence on the merits had been taken.

Civil trials
In a civil trial, this will depend on the province, but in Ontario:

Where a judge has commenced hearing a matter sitting alone and ... dies without giving a decision ...
a party may make a motion to the chief judge for an order that the matter be reheard.


Under Criminal Rule 25, a new judge will be appointed to hear the case. That judge can either familiarize himself with the record and resume the trial, or he can order a new trial.
